# Passing values from a Lua function to TeX

Tags: lua, luacode

The answer is probably simple but I can't find anything in the documentation

For example:

```
\begin{luacode}
function divmod(a,b)
    local q = 0
    local r = a
    while not (r < b) do
        q = q+1
        r = r-b
    end
    return q,r
end
\end{luacode}
```

I compile of course with lualatex and I want to assign for example the result `q`and `r` of
`divmod(\c,\d)` with `\def\c{45}` and `def\d{7}` to two macros `\x` and `\y`.
How do I do this? I know how to do it with one value but not two

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}

function divmod(a,b)
    local q = 0
    local r = a
    while not (r < b) do
        q = q+1
        r = r-b
    end
    return q,r
end

\end{luacode}


\begin{document} 
\def\c{45} \def\d{7}
???
\def\x{..?..} \def\y{..?..}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}

function divmod(a,b)
    local q = 0
    local r = a
    while not (r < b) do
        q = q+1
        r = r-b
    end
    return q,r
end

\end{luacode}
\def\x{}\def\y{}

\begin{document} 
\def\c{45} \def\d{7}

\directlua{
q,r=divmod(\c,\d)
token.set_macro("x",q)
token.set_macro("y", r)
}

x is \x, y is \y
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just discovered `token.set_macro`. Where is this defined?

Comment: I only found `set_macro` in the `LuaTeX` manual

Comment: @AlainMatthes it is in the section describing the `token` library, the luatex manual isn't always explicit but it avoids prefixing the names, but they won't work unprefixed by default

Answer (score 11):

The `\directlua` chunk returns the results in the format `{q}{r}`, so the macro `\divmodA` can read it as two parameters.

```
\directlua{
function divmod(a,b)
    local q = 0
    local r = a
    while not (r < b) do
        q = q+1
        r = r-b
    end
    return q,r
end
}
\def\divmod#1#2{%
   \expandafter\divmodA\directlua{q,r=divmod(#1,#2) tex.sprint("{",q,"}{",r,"}")}%
}
\def\divmodA#1#2{\def\x{#1}\def\y{#2}}

\divmod{45}{7}
x is \x, y is \y.

\bye
```

Comment: Interesting answer,thanks ! I didn't know that the \directlua chunk returns the results in the format `{q}{r}`

Comment: @AlainMatthes wipet means this function returns a brace pair due to the tex.sprint not that that is a general feature

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I misspoke and maybe wipet did too. I understood that the format was due to `tex.sprint("{",q,"}{",r,"}")}`but that is only valid if the author decides and if it is feasible! Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @AlainMatthes yes, the advantage of wipet's suggestion is it passes both values back from Lua to tex without hard coding tex macro names in the Lua side, it just returns `{6}{3}` so then you are free to do whatever you want on the tex side, perhaps define two macros, or perhaps use directly as argument to some two-argument macro, or whatever. Which reminds me, I should vote +1 here... done:-)

Answer (score 7):

If the results of `divmod` are always to be stored in `\q` and `\r`, the following solution may be of interest.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}

function divmod ( a , b )
    local q = 0
    local r = a
    while not (r < b) do
        q = q+1
        r = r-b
    end
    tex.sprint("\\def\\q{"..q.."}")
    tex.sprint("\\def\\r{"..r.."}")
end

\end{luacode}

% LaTeX utility macro:
\newcommand\divmod[2]{\directlua{divmod(#1,#2)}}

\begin{document} 
\divmod{45}{7}
\q, \r

\def\c{100} \def\d{11}
\directlua{divmod(\c,\d)}
\q, \r
\end{document}
```